# Hamachi for Web Surfing

Tags: security, freebsd, vpn

I recently installed Hamachi on my FreeBSD 9 and I want to know how can I browse web anonymously by this software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hamachi isn't meant for that. It's a VPN service/software, not an anonymous browsing helper.

You could use Hamachi to tunnel traffic to another machine that runs something like [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/), possibly with an http proxy too or whatever else anonymizing techniques you will.
Hamachi itself doesn't provide that. It lets you build a private network, but you have to deal with interactions outside that network.